# How to sync 3 processes executing functions X and Y using semaphore?

Tags: concurrency, semaphore, critical-section

There are *3 processes* running *concurrently* executing `X()` and `Y()` *repeatedly*.

Requirements:

- Only at most *2 process* may execute `Y()`, that is, the last process should skip the `Y()` function when it sees that the *other two process* are *executing* the `Y()` function.
- The *process currently not allowed to execute* `Y()` should still be executing their `X()` function.
- `X()` *can be executed by all 3 process simultaneously*

Here is my Pseudocode, using the traditional *P* and *V* operation *definitions* of semaphores, where *ProcA ProcB and ProcC* are **concurrent**

```
SEMVAR = 2 # Only at most 2 process may execute Y()

def ProcB():
    while True: # X() and Y() executes repeatedly
        X()
        P(SEMVAR)
        Y()
        V(SEMVAR)


def ProcC():
    while True:
        X()
        P(SEMVAR)
        Y()
        V(SEMVAR)

def ProcA():
    while True:
        X()
        P(SEMVAR)
        Y()
        V(SEMVAR)
```

While this code does only allow *at most 2 process* to execute `Y()`, it *prevents* the last process from executing `X()` while it's waiting to use `Y()` again. I simply want it to skip `Y()` and *still* execute `X()` in the process.